Flutter - Xiaomi Note 12 mobile doesn't utilise hotloading etc in debug mode
My Xiaomi Note 12 mobile doesn't utilise hotloading etc in debug mode
Help Request
I can run "flutter run" and have it boot up on my phone (phone is set up for developer mode), but the terminal window just says

"Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
10,3s",

There is no ability to utilise reloading, hot reloading etc.
Seems to work find on emulator devices.
Is there something I need to do on my phone?

As a Flutter developer, I can confirm that the hot/instant reload feature doesn't work on Xiaomi phones. I use the Xiaomi Mi Mix 2, and it's a pain because I have to restart the application completely for every change. This way, we lose the main benefit of Flutter.

This wasn't a problem on onlder Xiaomi devices I don't think. I had the Play (android 8) and it ws fine. Only since getting a new one (Android 12,  tried on both Miui and Harmony OS)
